# javax.servlet.UnavailableException:Servlet class MyClass is not a javax.servlet.Servlet while migrating from jdk8 to openjdk11& weblogic to jetty

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jetty, openjdk-11

I am facing MyClass is not a javax.servlet.Servlet warn and application is not going up while deploying in jetty server.

Earlier when running on jdk8 and weblogic it was working fine. i am facing this issue while migrating from jdk8 to openjdk11 and weblogic to jetty.

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SomeName</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>StaticQueueConnectionServlet</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Soap11HttpPort</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyClass</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SchedulerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SchedulerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Soap11HttpPort</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Soap11HttpPort</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SchedulerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SchedulerServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My webservice class

```
@javax.jws.WebService(serviceName = "XXXXXX", 
name = "Soap11HttpPort", 
targetNamespace = "xxxxxxx", 
endpointInterface = "MyInterface")
public final class MyClass implements MyInterface {

@javax.annotation.Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

public Resp ping(final Request request) throws Exception {

    return pesponse;
}

public Response printDocument(
        final Request request) throws Exception {

    try {
        final MessageContext ctx = context.getMessageContext();
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);

        return response;

    } catch (Exception exc) {

    }

}
```

}

I am Getting

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class MyClass is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:547)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:745)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:739)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1443)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:821)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:276)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:436)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:622)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:402)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:318)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$0(XmlConfiguration.java:1824)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1773)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

Comment: Well the error message is right. `MyClass` is not a `javax.servlet.Servlet`. Did WebLogic not care that you're trying to use a non-servlet as a servlet?

Comment: @Kayaman, yes weblogic didnot care, it's working fine in weblogic with java 8. Now i am facing issues while migrating from java 8 to openjdk11 and to jetty

Comment: The MyClass appears to be a JAX-WS Endpoint, which is never a Servlet, if WebLogic deployed that as a Servlet, then WebLogic did you no favors.  Have you considered either using standard servlets, or deploying to a JAX-WS container?